# My Min and Max number in an array functions shows anything but the Max and Min

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;

void buildArray(int arr[], int size) {

        srand(time(NULL));
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            arr[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
        }

}

void showArray(int arr[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        cout << i << arr[i] << " ";
    }

}

void curveArray(int arr[], int size, int curve) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        arr[i] += curve;
    }

}

int maxNum(int arr[], int size) {

int maxnum = arr[0];
int position = 0;

for (int i =1; i < size; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] > maxnum ) {
        maxnum = arr[i];
        position = i;
    }
}
  return position;
}

int minNum(int arr[], int size) {

int minnum = arr[0];
int position = 0;

for (int i =1; i < size; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] < minnum) {
        minnum = arr[i];
        position = i;
    }
}
    return position;
}



int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    int arrayx[size];
    buildArray(arrayx, size);
    showArray(arrayx, size);
    //curveArray(arrayx, size, 5);
    //showArray(arrayx, size);

    int maxVal = maxNum(arrayx, size);
    cout << endl << endl << maxVal;
    int minVal = minNum(arrayx, size);
    cout << endl << endl << minVal;


    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I try to run this code it generates a random array (as it's supposed exactly) but then when I use the functions to get the Max and Min Values it generates random number so here's the output when I run it

http://imageshack.com/a/img27/725/4jv9.png

This is from a C++ practice video but It works with the tutor but not with me and it's almost the same code!!

Comment: You're returning the position and then printing that as the value.

Comment: Learn to use your debugger....

Comment: Well I changed the return statement to return maxnum and minnum but the same thing and the video used return position By the way!

Answer (score 1):

Your code returns **positions** of min and max values. To take values use

```
int maxVal = arrayx[maxNum(arrayx, size)];
cout << endl << endl << maxVal;
int minVal = arrayx[minNum(arrayx, size)];
cout << endl << endl << minVal;
```

also your `showArray` is incorrect. Change it to

```
void showArray(int arr[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I canged it to return minnum nd maxnum but the same thing, although the video return position

Comment: Your `showArray` shows index and value without spaces between them. So you receive "037" for value "37" on index "0", "160" for value "60" on index "1" and so on.

Comment: Are you satisfied with the answer? If yes - please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning **position** of `Max` and `Min` value from the function, not the actual `max` and `min` values. It should be

```
return arr[position];
```

instead of

```
return position;
```

Comment: The same problem! Just random numbers!

Comment: What random numbers? Post the image link if you can.

Comment: You have put the old image given in OP, what error come after applying the change suggested.

Comment: here's the output after applying changes!